# How to get JdbcClientTokenServices to store tokens in datasource?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Here is my code, I need to setMandatory to 'false' because the resource provider does not return the 'state' parameter as the Oauth2 specification recommends.

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
        AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
        authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.setStateMandatory(false);
        AccessTokenProviderChain provider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.asList(authorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider));
        provider.setClientTokenServices(clientTokenServices());
        template.setAccessTokenProvider(provider);
        return template;
    }
```

Here is the code from the [github example](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-oauth2-integration-tests/blob/master/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/ClientApplication.java) that works with H2:

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
        AccessTokenProviderChain provider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.asList(new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider()));
        provider.setClientTokenServices(clientTokenServices());
        return template;
    }
```

1. I changed the LONGVARBINARY to BLOB for all cases in schema.sql, in order to get the scripts to work with MySQL. I can verify that my database is created.
2. template.setAccessTokenProvider(provider); without this line, I still get the CSRF problems because the resource provider isn't returning the "state" param.
3. I am using an AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails just like the example as well.  I also setup my accessTokenRequest and clientTokenServices identical to the example.

After the user authorizes the client and is redirected back, the code is exchanged for a token and things are working.  I can see that my client does have an access token.  I expect to see that access token stored in the database as well.  I am creating the database schema on startup and the datasource appears to be setup properly.  I don't get any errors during runtime that point to configuration issues either.  Everything else is working as expected, I just don't get any data in any of the tables where I expect to see information about the access and refresh tokens sent back from the resource server.

Comment: I ran into the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908203/spring-boot-oauth2-sso-with-access-refresh-tokens-stored-in-a-database Do you already found a solution how to correctly implement it ?